# When do the sine components of a Fourier series vanish?

Tags: fourier-series

A Fourier series is given by:

$$
s_N(x) = \sum c_n \cdot e^{i \frac{2\pi n x}{P}}
$$

With Euler's identity, the exponential can be converted to a sums of sines and cosines.

When do the sine components of a Fourier series vanish?

Comment: It means that you are dealing with an even function.

Comment: When $c_n=c_{-n}$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 2):

When you are dealing with an even function. -- [Jack D'Aurizio](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893501/when-do-the-sine-components-of-a-fourier-serie-vanish#comment1844493_893501)

When $c_n=c_{-n}$ for all $n$. -- [Henning Makholm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893501/when-do-the-sine-components-of-a-fourier-serie-vanish#comment1844495_893501)